# Unexpected token: on compressing js file

Tags: javascript

I have tried compressing a JavaScript file, with both http://jscompress.com and "uglifyjs" (`uglifyjs main.js --compress --mangle > main.min.js`), but I get the following error:

> File main.js: Unexpected token: name «sidebarSubcategory», expected: punc «;» (line: 17, col: 8)

In the `main.js` I have the following function:

```
function openSubcategory(el, id) {
  let sidebarSubcategory = document.getElementById("sidebar-subcategory-" + id);
  if (el.innerHTML === '+') {
    el.innerHTML = '-';
    sidebarSubcategory.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = '+';
    sidebarSubcategory.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
  }
}
```

I don't get it.

Comment: How are you compressing your JS?

Comment: using this tool (https://jscompress.com/) or using  uglifyjs (uglifyjs main.js --compress --mangle > main.min.js
)

Comment: can you paste your entire code?

Comment: @Phillip sure. I have updated the post

Comment: @Phillip why do you need more code. You can reproduce the same error with the given code. using the tool he provided

Comment: calin, you can solve the erro by checking the checkbox Ecmascript 2019

Comment: @Kevin.a yes I just discovered that. @calin24 It seems the issue with jscompress.com is that it doesnt parse es2015. No `let`, `const` etc. Enabling es2019 or changing the `let` to `var` solves the issue.

Comment: ohhh...i get it. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compression tool you're using doesnt support the new syntax. Changing let to var or checking the "Use ecmascript 2019" checkbox will solve your issue.

And as for uglifyjs, you can use this tool its from the same developers of uglifyjs but for es6 syntax :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es

Comment: and if i want to use uglifyjs ? how can i tell to use es 2015 ?